# No push notifications if run the app from Xcode. TestFlight works

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, testflight

When I run the app from Xcode it doesn't get push notifications, but the app registers for them successfully. 
When I send same version of the app to TestFlight than everything is ok.

There are production and development APNS certificates and I have both of them in keychain.

I was trying to test it with Pusher and I used .p12 file created from dev certificate and it works.

P.S. everything was fine couple weeks ago.

Comment: Can you please try to get the push notification certificate for development mode. Then only you can get the push notification in development time. Other wise you didn't get the push notification.

Comment: Let check your server called push notification from dev cer or prod cer when you run the app from Xcode.